# RDLC report in Visual Studio 2017 does not run on hosting with .NET Framework 3.5, why?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, rdlc

We have rented a hosting that offers me to work with ASP.NET and .NET Framework 3.5; everything worked fine, until we got to the reporting part; where I had to created a dataset and a RDLC report. When I update my site, it doesn't start anymore because it does not recognize the report libraries.

How could I solve it please?

These entries were added to the `web.config`; without it, even my database-bound dataview worked fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hard time reading the image; better post the config as code.

It looks like you are using traditional ASP.NET. I had used the following config in an previous project:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">  
    <assemblies>  
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />  
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />  
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" /> </assemblies>  
    <buildProviders>  
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> </buildProviders>  
</compilation>
```